# Method to create new SQL Server CE DB file. Suggest Improvements

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I am using following code to create SQL Server CE database file programmatically. I am using C# 2008.

```
    /* Create a new SQL Server CE database file programatically */
    protected void CreateDB(string _databaseFileName, bool _encryptFile, string _password)
    {
        if (File.Exists(_databaseFileName))
            MessageBox.Show("A file with this name already exists.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        else
        {
            string connectionString = string.Format("DataSource=\"{0}\"; Password='{1}'", _databaseFileName, _password);
            SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(connectionString);
            engine.CreateDatabase();
        }
    }
```

I want to improve the above code. My queries are below:

1. This method is contained in a protected class. I want these methods to be called directly without creating an instance of this class. Suggest a way with no overhead.
2. Though I am passing a **bool** to determine whether the user wants to encrypt file or not, but not used in the connection string line. I am not following which other parameter need to be included for encryption and how to include encryption algorithm.
3. I want to include exception handling with least overhead. I want to include "*using*", but not following how to modify the above code with this.

Comment: Sounds like an interview/exam question almost.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make the method `static`.
2. If you include a password in the connection string, the database file is automatically encrypted.
3. Not sure what you mean by this one. You should be catching `SqlCeException` in the else.  Also, you should wrap the `SqlCeEngine` in a using statement.

   ```
   try
   {
      string connectionString = string.Format("DataSource=\"{0}\"; Password='{1}'", _databaseFileName, _password);
      using (SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(connectionString))
      {
         engine.CreateDatabase();
      }
   }
   catch (SqlCeException)
   {
   }
   ```

Comment: I don't want to use try..Catch. Secondly, I want to include the encryption algorithm.

Comment: Not sure how you are going to handle exceptions without a try..catch. Why don't you want to use a try block?  I'm not sure if you can set the encryption algorithm or not.